# What is wrong with this if/else conditional code?

Tags: python

```
def who_are_you(tall,ginger,wears lenses):
    if tall and ginger and wears glasses:
        return "student 1"
    if tall and not ginger and not wears lenses:
        return " student 2"
    if ginger and wears lenses and not tall:
        return "student 3"
    if wears lenses and not tall and not ginger:
        return "student 4"
    if tall and wears lenses and not ginger:
        return "student 5"
    else:
        return "bossman"    

#This is just for you to see what happens when the function is called
print who_are_you(True, True, True)
```

Comment: `wears lenses != wears glasses`.  Can you have identifiers in Python that contain spaces?

Comment: What makes you *think* something is wrong with this? Does it produce an error message? If so, what does it say? Does it produce the wrong answer? If so, what does it produce? Did you professor tell you it was wrong? If so, what did she say? *Read and understand the error indication you received. If you don't understand it, say so.*

Comment: Other than the issue pointed out in karthikr's answer, remember that a function always quits at the first `return` before it even reads the rest, so writing this kind of conditionals in general is not very good practice.

Comment: @AbhranilDas: Why would it need to read the rest if one of the conditions is already fulfilled?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well in this case it does not, but in a general case if a later condition (say, `is prime`) is a more specific subset of an earlier condition (say, `is odd`), the function will never respond to it even if it is satisfied (in this case for a prime number).

Comment: @AbhranilDas: Presumably the programmer is aware of that general case, and will adjust his code as necessary to fulfill that case.

Answer (score 4):

You issue is with the variable name `wears lenses`

It should be `wears_lenses` or something else. You cannot use whitespaces in your variable name.

Also, you have an issue with the variable names: `wears glasses` should be `wears_lenses`

Comment: *Here, it not evaluating expressions like - `if tall and not ginger and not wears lenses` correctly for python to give you accurate results.* - what?

Comment: Also, I prefer 'elif' when you have multiple if conditions